# Is it possible to get inverted result from existent data by user input?

Tags: mysql

Sorry for my title, I don't know how to describe it.

I have a table `t1` as follow:

```
id  t_id   time
 1   1     201501
 2   1     201502
```

I want to get a recordset in a specify period like `201501, 201502, 201503, 201504, 201505, 201506`, and the time not in `t1`. The specify period passed by user input.

I want the result like this:

```
id  t_id   time
 1   1     201503
 2   1     201504
 3   1     201505
 4   1     201506
```

Is it possible to get the result in one sql?

And I use php to collect user input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM 
     ( 
       SELECT 201501 user_input
        UNION
       SELECT 201502
        UNION
       SELECT 201503
        UNION
       SELECT 201504
        UNION
       SELECT 201505
        UNION
       SELECT 201506
     ) a
  LEFT 
  JOIN t1 b
    ON b.time = a.user_input
 WHERE b.id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this (sorry i have no Database here, so i can't test it): the trick is to select your values with UNION SELECT first.

```
SELECT v.x from (SELECT 201501 v
UNION SELECT 201502 v
UNION SELECT 201503 v
UNION SELECT 201504 v
UNION SELECT 201505 v
UNION SELECT 201506 v) x
 WHERE v.x not in (SELECT time FROM t1)
```